# Why Glide is not loading Drawable asBitmap?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am working on a side project and in notification i wanted to show some default place Holder(drawable) in ImageView.

So i tried this:

```
Glide.with(appContext)
     .load(iconDrawable)
     .into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
          override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
          }

          override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    val resBitmap : Bitmap = Utils.drawableToBitmap(resource)
                    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.primaryIcon, resBitmap))
          }
     })
```

Above code is working perfectly but as you can notice i don't want to handle creation and conversion of **Drawable to Bitmap** .So i tried to use `asBitmap()`.

```
Glide.with(appContext)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(iconDrawable)
     .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
          override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
          }

          override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.primaryIcon, resource))
          }
     })
```

I expected to work but bitmap it empty and drawable is not loading to the view.
even i tried using placeholder(),error() nothing worked

```
Glide.with(appContext)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(iconDrawable)
     .placeholder(iconDrawable)
     .error(iconDrawable)
     .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
          override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
          }

          override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.primaryIcon, resource))
          }
     })
```

*NOTE:Above case arises even if i use NotificationTarget*

Answer (score 0):

// try this, ...
remoteView.setImageBitmap(R.id.yourImageView, bitmap);

Comment: Didn't work the issue is not with remoteView its glide which is not returning the Bitmap for the required vector drawable.